# App Engine error log says "stacktrace () not available"

Tags: google-app-engine

In App Engine's log, I can see that sometimes there is an error.
Unfortunately there are no more details than the time, URL, parameters and this:

```
HttpMyReceiver: stacktrace () not available
```

How can I get more info about the error?

---

*More about my code, in case it helps: HttpMyReceiver is a class inheriting webapp.RequestHandler so it answers to HTTP requests. Its work is not that heavy in my opinion, no crazy loops as all of the heavy duty work is done by cron jobs. It should not be necessary, but in case you insist here is [the code](https://github.com/iniju/ankidroid-triage/blob/master/receive_ankicrashes.py#L465). In fact it is HttpCrashReceiver as its job is to receive crash reports from an Android app.*

Comment: It would help if you told us more about your app. `HttpMyReceiver` sounds like a class your code has, but you haven't told us anything about your code.

Comment: @Nick: It is actually open source so the whole source code is available: https://github.com/iniju/ankidroid-triage/blob/master/receive_ankicrashes.py#L465 I thought it was a common error and somebody would know a trick without looking at the source code.

Comment: Please don't expect us to read all your source code in order to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Nick: I don't expect you to read all the code. As as said in my last comment, I hope someone will recognize the message as a common error caused by X (see for instance lrussell's answer). I am the first to be sorry that I don't know which part of the code causes the error. I will add some info about the code that might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own code outputs this on [line 552](https://github.com/iniju/ankidroid-triage/blob/master/receive_ankicrashes.py#L552), if the `body` variable is not set. `body` is set from the contents of the 'stacktrace' parameter to the request.

Comment: Whoa, how could I miss that? So sorry for wasting your time! I haven't touched the code for ages and was convinced the "stacktrace" was a reference to some exception sent by App Engine... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

All the references I have seen with "stacktrace not available" have been caused by an OutOfMemoryError; not sure if that is the issue in your case, but maybe you could try to get more information about the available memory using the App Engine [quota API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/quota/package-summary.html).